# I can't find imap() in itertools in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, python-itertools

I have a problem that I want to solve with `itertools.imap()`. I imported `itertools` and called `itertools.imap()`, but apparently `itertools` doesn't have attribute `imap`. What's going wrong?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> dir(itertools)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_grouper',     '_tee', '_tee_dataobject', 'accumulate', 'chain', 'combinations', 'combinations_with_replacement', 'compress', 'count', 'cycle', 'dropwhile', 'filterfalse', 'groupby', 'islice', 'permutations', 'product', 'repeat', 'starmap', 'takewhile', 'tee', 'zip_longest']
>>> itertools.imap()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
itertools.imap()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imap'
```

Comment: It can be interesting also to take a look at [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) in pyhton3.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`itertools.imap()` is in Python 2, but not in Python 3.

Actually, that function was moved to just the `map` function in Python 3 and if you want to use the old Python 2 map, you must use `list(map())`.

Comment: thanks buddy, I was also trying to import accumulate but was not working. The problem was python2.x , Now switched to python3.X it starts working

Answer (score 17):

If you want something that works in both Python 3 and Python 2, you can do something like:

```
try:
    from itertools import imap
except ImportError:
    # Python 3...
    imap=map
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using Python 3, therefore there is no `imap` function in `itertools` module. It was removed, because global function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) now returns iterators.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
imap = lambda *args, **kwargs: list(map(*args, **kwargs))
```

In fact!! :)

```
import itertools
itertools.imap = lambda *args, **kwargs: list(map(*args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: This trick works for me. I want to get sum of all tuple in a list & this is a easy way to use it in python 3

Comment: The `itertools.imap` function in Python 2 and the `map` function in Python 3 both return [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). While this answer will technically work, it calls `list` on the result set. This is fine if the results fit in memory but may not be desirable in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [`python-future` idoms](http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html) for universal Python 2/3 code, like this:

```
# Works in both Python 2 and 3:
from builtins import map
```

You then have to refactor your code to use `map` everywhere you were using `imap` before:

```
myiter = map(func, myoldlist)

# `myiter` now has the correct type and is interchangeable with `imap`
assert isinstance(myiter, iter)
```

You do need to install future for this to work on both 2 and 3:

```
pip install future
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 2to3 script (https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) which is part of every Python installation to translate your program or whole projects from Python 2 to Python 3.

```
python <path_to_python_installation>\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w <your_file>.py
```

(-w option writes modifications to file, a backup is stored)