# Convert list to string using python

Tags: python, list

I have the list it contain int ,float and string:

```
lists = [10, "test", 10.5]
```

How Can i convert above list to string? I have tried:

```
val = ','.join(lists)
print val
```

I am getting error like this:

```
sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate item in list to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453580/concatenate-item-in-list-to-strings)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly convert integers to string using `str`using `map` function then use `join` function-

```
>>> ','.join(map(str,[10,"test",10.5]) )#since added comma inside the single quote output will be comma(,) separated
>>> '10,test,10.5'
```

Or if you want to convert each element of list into string then try-

```
>>> map(str,[10,"test",10.5])
>>> ['10', 'test', '10.5']
```

Or use `itertools` for memory efficiency(large data)

```
>>>from itertools import imap
>>>[i for i in imap(str,[10,"test",10.5])]
>>>['10', 'test', '10.5']
```

Or simply use list comprehension

```
>>>my_list=['10', 'test', 10.5]
>>>my_string_list=[str(i) for i in my_list]
>>>my_string_list
>>>['10', 'test', '10.5']
```

Comment: `imap` no longer included in `itertools` using Python 3. Use `map` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271712/i-cant-find-imap-in-itertools-in-python

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to send the whole thing to `str()` or `repr()`:

```
>>> lists = [10, "test", 10.5]
>>> str(lists)
"[10, 'test', 10.5]"
```

`repr()` may produce a different result from `str()` depending on what's defined for each type of object in the `list`. The point of `repr()` is that you can send such strings back to `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()` to get the original object back:

```
>>> import ast
>>> lists = [10, "test", 10.5]
>>> ast.literal_eval(repr(lists))
[10, 'test', 10.5]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ['b','c','d']
strng = ''
for i in a:
   strng +=str(i)
print strng
```

Comment: a = ['b','c','d']   ==> Let this be a list 
strng = ''         ==> Lets initialise a variable strng with empty string "
for i in a:         ==> Interate over each element of list and concatenate with strng
   strng +=str(i)
print strng      ==> Finally print the required strng

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting because `join` wants elements to be `string` type, but in your list there is `integer` too, so 1st you have to convert them to type string.

you can use list comprehension and str and join to join them

```
>>> lists = [10,"test",10.5]
>>> ",".join(str(x) for x in lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass each item in your list as a string into the ','.join(sequence). Consider using:

val = ','.join([str(item) for item in lists])

print val

Comment: Simplest solution, using a list comprehension and taking advantage that `str(item)` doesn't change `item` if it is already a `str`. This or TigerhawkT3 solution should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert each element in the list to a string, you could do it simply using a for-loop.

```
for i in range(len(lists)):
    lists[i] = str(lists[i])
```

Alternatively, if you want to make one string where all elements are joined together, you could edit the code above slightly.

```
string_of_lists = ""
for i in lists:
    string_of_lists += str(i)
```

As you can tell, this is another way of doing it, apart from the other solutions using join.

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible. Here `x` variable is list.

```
>>> '%s'*len(x) % tuple(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5618893/9424959)

```
 list=['a/b/c', 'd/e/f']
 file_list_string= ' '.join(list)
 file_list_string= ' '.join(str(file) for file in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import functools
lists = [10,"test",10.5]
print(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+","+y,list(map(str,lists))))
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: in the reduce function initially x and y take the value from list and after that x store the resultant values and y gets the new value from list.  (eg. x=10 and y= test then x+","+y = 10,test  and now in second step x= 10,test and y=10.5 now x+","+y) become 10,test,10.5  resultant answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could always do it the dirty way:

```
     list_name = ["a", "b", "c"];
     string_name = "";

     for c in list_name:
         string_name += c
     print(string_name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    "abc"
```

That should work with ints, floats, and strings, always converting them to string type.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time answering this question. However, please try your solution with the list provided by the OP. Maybe you want to change your solution aftwerwards.