# how to convert list into string in python

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm getting output as list value as shown below
[Row(column1='a,b,c,d')]

how to convert this to string value
needed output:
'a,b,c,d'

how to achieve this using python/pyspark?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert list to string using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629703/convert-list-to-string-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is just a list of PySpark `Row` objects, and in order to get values out of those objects, you just need to loop through it

```
print([r['column1'] for r in df.collect()])
```